# GGplot geom_ribbon - Only color between 2 points

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

I have 2 sets of numerical data (called **L.MEAN** and **P.MEAN**) plotted as 2 lines on the same plot (with the same x axis, **Time**). I want to color the space between the lines and the space between the lower line (**P.MEAN**) and the x axis, but only within a certain range of x (between **WIT** and **WOT**). For clarity, **WIT** and **WOT** are just numbers that I obtained through the `which()` function.

This is what I have written:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = Time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = L.MEAN, color = "deepskyblue3"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = P.MEAN, color = "deeppink"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = P.MEAN,
                  ymax = L.MEAN,
                  xmin = WIT,
                  xmax = WOT),
              alpha = 0.4,
              fill = "deepskyblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0,
                  ymax = P.MEAN,
                  xmin = WIT,
                  xmax = WOT),
              alpha = 0.4,
              fill = "deeppink")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, as it colors the entire x axis.
[image]

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for providing code to produce the plot. I think you will get helpful answers if you are able to provide the data that is used in the script, or a similar toy dataset. See "providing a minimal dataset" for suggestions on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning! I'll try to provide a similar dataset (I cannot share my true data though); thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to color only a range of your chart, then you have to filter the data used for `geom_ribbon` for the desired range. Additionally I fixed the assignments of the colors for the lines by setting the colors via `scale_color_manual`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Time = seq_len(125),
  L.MEAN = runif(125, 50, 100),
  P.MEAN = runif(125, 25, 50)
)

WIT <- 35
WOT <- 70

ggplot(data, aes(x = Time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = L.MEAN, color = "lmean"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = P.MEAN, color = "pmean"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = ~ subset(.x, Time >= WIT & Time <= WOT),
    aes(
      ymin = P.MEAN,
      ymax = L.MEAN
    ),
    alpha = 0.4,
    fill = "deepskyblue"
  ) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = ~ subset(.x, Time >= WIT & Time <= WOT),
    aes(
      ymin = 0,
      ymax = P.MEAN
    ),
    alpha = 0.4,
    fill = "deeppink"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(lmean = "deepskyblue", pmean = "deeppink")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! That works perfectly